# How can I sort IP addresses and integers in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, integer, ip

I have a list of IPs and integers that I'd like to python to sort by the 4th column:

172.2.174.86    172.2.15.65 69694            42272874

172.2.200.100   172.2.15.20                   14                4326

10.1.162.12     172.2.15.162                4741              170676

172.2.174.86    172.2.15.64                46021            33956341

10.1.167.237    172.2.15.69                  921              133574

The problem is Python can't seem to handle IP addresses and integers in the same list. I can only sort alphabetically. How do I do correct sorting based on the value of the 4th column Here's what I have:

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()

lines=[x.split() for x in lines]

for i in lines:
 i.reverse()

lines.sort(cmp, reverse=True)

for i in lines:
 print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt find clean easy way to do this in py w/o long complex functions and lambdas,

easiest way by far,

*pip install sh*

```
from sh import sort
sort('-nr', '/tmp/file1', '-o', '/tmp/file1')
```

sh module is fantastic.

Answer (score 6):

Is the following what you're after?

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()
lines = [x.split() for x in lines]
lines.sort(cmp, key=lambda x:int(x[3]))
for i in lines:
  print i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '))

def intkey(row):
    return int(row[3])

data.sort(key=intkey, reverse=True)
print data
```

---

the results:

```
[['172.2.174.86', '172.2.15.65', '69694', '42272874'],
 ['172.2.174.86', '172.2.15.64', '46021', '33956341'],
 ['10.1.162.12', '172.2.15.162', '4741', '170676'],
 ['10.1.167.237', '172.2.15.69', '921', '133574'],
 ['172.2.200.100', '172.2.15.20', '14', '4326']]
```

Answer (score 1):

you ip integers are stored in string, right? and the 4th column is part of the string? however you can do something like

```
l.sort(key=lambda x:x.split()[3], reverse=True)
```

or if you want more control, you can define a function that takes 2 string and determine wich is the highest, then pass that func to sort through cmp argument

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()
lines=[x.split() for x in lines]
lines.sort(key=lambda l: int(l[3]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to reverse your lines. You should be able to simply sort the lines using

```
lines.sort( lambda x, y: cmp( int(x[3]), int(y[3]) ) )
```

assuming that you always have an integral value in your fourth column.

Good link discussing Python sequences and how to manipulate them: [Effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm)